# removing product from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want remove the product row, from the table, how i can do it to an element that will be added?

here my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YgQ7y/

HTML:

```
<select name="produtos" id="lista_produtos">
    <option value="selecione...">Selecione...</option>
    <option value="value 1">value 1</option>
    <option value="value 2">value 2</option>
    <option value="value 3">value 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="quant_produtos" name="amount" placeholder="Quant">
<button id="add_produto">add product</button>
<br><br>
<table border="1" width="100%" id="cesta_produtos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name:</td>
            <td>quant:</td>
            <td>remove</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#add_produto').on('click', function () {

    var $table = $('#cesta_produtos tbody'), // Product Table

        $list = $('#lista_produtos').val(), // Select with products

        $quant = $('#quant_produtos').val(), // Quantity field

        $remove = "<a href='#' class='del_produto'>x</a>"; // Link to remove product

    // Insert the product inside the table
    $table.append("<tr><td>" + $list + "</td><td>" + $quant + "</td><td>" + $remove + "</td></tr>");

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/YgQ7y/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

This uses a *delegated event handler*. Basically it listens for any 'click' events bubbled up to the document, *then* it applies a jQuery selector, *then* it applies the function to any matching elements that generated the event.

The advantages are twofold. First the items do not need to exist until the event occurs, but will still be found and, secondly, this means a single event handler processes any number of items (rather than lots if single event handlers attached to individual elements).

### Guideline:

You will normally listen for delegated events at the first non-changing ancestor of the dynamic elements (so maybe your table element `#cesta_produtos`). If one is not available/convenient, use document (do not use `$('body')` as there are some weird side-effects on some event types, including click).

e.g.

```
$('#cesta_produtos').on('click', '.del_produto', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Note: As your links are a href="#" you need to stop the default action or a long page will scroll to the top when you click a delete "x". Just return false from the click handler or use `preventDefault()` on an event argument.

```
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   return false;
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have update your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgQ7y/5/)

You need to use the `.on` jQuery method and delegate the event:

```
$('#cesta_produtos').on('click', '.del_produto', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
})
```